# How to use jQuery event delegation here?

Tags: jquery, html, custom-events

I load content into a `div` at some point dynamically, from my main page script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myDiv').load('layer2.html');
}
```

Then, I want to receive custom events sent by `layer2.html`'s corresponding script on the main page script. If I add this on the main one:

```
$(document).on('event1', function () {
        window.alert('event1 received');
});
```

And the following in the `layer2.html` script:

```
var event = new Event('event1');
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

It works (the alert shows). Note that above isn't jQuery. But triggering the event with jQuery instead as the way below:

```
$(document).trigger('event1');
```

Does not work, even when I apply the following change in an attempt to succeed on [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) system, which from my previous readings I understand that is what my case is all about:

```
$(document).on('event1', '#myDiv', function() {
    window.alert('event1 received');
});
```

Finally, I want to note I found similar questions but they only dealed with `click` events or other native ones, rather than custom events.

How to fix my issue using jQuery and *event delegation*?

Comment: you don't need event delegation here, the document isn't a dynamic element.

Comment: I can't recreate your problem. Triggering works both immediately, and after a delay. https://jsfiddle.net/9g1v6wrb/

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for your time, my problem was that I was including jQuery again on the included file (`layer1.html`), possibly resulting in two unrelated jQuery instances, with different events storage. Making sure jQuery is included only on the main file allows me to use easy triggers again. Thanks!